# Как повесить скрипт на только что появившийся объект. Unity3d

Tags: c#, unity3d

Есть скрипт, висящий на враге(скрипт Enemy), на сцене. Впоследствии я перетаскиваю врага в Prefab и некоторые gameobjects в данном скрипте пропадают, потому что они либо в Canvas, либо находятся на сцене, то есть никак их не добавить, так как они не Prefabs.

Тогда в такой ситуации такой вопрос, можно ли данный скрипт как-то навесить на врага при его instantiate(появлении) на сцене или перекинуть с другого объекта на него данный скрипт?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ответ на вопрос

> можно ли данный скрипт как-то навесить на врага при его instantiate(появлении) на сцене

Да, можно.

Как:

**[Instantiate](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Object.Instantiate.html)** возвращает тот самый объект, который был инициализирован, а **[AddComponent](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GameObject.AddComponent.html)**  помогает добавить нужный компонент на объект.

---

Но судя по вашей ситуации вы что-то не так делаете. И вам нужно менять что-то в вашей логике или действиях, а не искать пути обхода проблемы

Answer (score 0):

Самый простой способ - с помощью [FindGameObjectsWithTag](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag.html) найти необходимые GameObject, предварительно повесив на них тег, к примеру EnemyComponent.

После чего, как я понимаю, вам необходимо сделать копию уже существующего на сцене объекта, для этого, как уже было сказано прибегнуть к [Instantiate](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Object.Instantiate.html). Если нужно просто обратиться к уже существующему объекту, то будет достаточно [FindGameObjectsWithTag](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag.html).

А вообще, для решения подобных проблем стоит задуматься о создании Менеджера проекта.